# What is the difference between HEAD:master and HEAD?

Tags: git

```
git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME_PRODUCTION.git HEAD
```

and

```
git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD:master
```

It looks like the HEAD:master able to overwrite the .gitignore file and HEAD can't.

Comment: This syntax doesn't determine whether `.gitignore` - or any other specific content - can be updated; I'm curious what's leading you in that direction, because it sounds like there may be something else going on

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in target branch on remote server.

Let's assume you sit on branch `foobar`.

```
git checkout foobar
..workwork..
git push origin HEAD
```

`HEAD` the newest version of **your current local branch**. So, it means `foobar` in this example. Therefore, this command will simply send `foobar` to the remote server. On the remote server it will update/overwrite a branch that 'matches'*) the one you are sending. Usually, that will mean sending `foobar` **as** `foobar`. No suprises here.

On the other hand

```
git checkout foobar
..workwork..
git push origin HEAD:master
```

explictly instructs git to send your HEAD **as master**. That means, it will send the your most recent `foobar` to the remote server as `master` on the remote server. It's just it, exactly it. Your local `master` will not change and will stay untouched. Remote `foobar`, if it exists at all, will not change. However, remote `master` will be now synced with your local `foobar`

---

*) it is the client (your local side) that decides which branch to choose on the remote side. Default mappings between local-branch and remote-branch are kept in your `.git/config` file. It is absolutely possible to make your local branch `aaa` send automatically to remote `aaa` or to remote `bbb`, so in fact I cannot tell you where exactly will `git push origin xxxx` push the xxxx branch - it depends on the mappings - and you can alter them by `--set-upstream` or by just editing the config file. On the other hand `git push origin xxx:yyy` always means exactly that: send x as y.

---

As for the `.gitignore` part - it has nothing to do. Neither pull nor push has anything to `.gitignore`. Git-ignore does not prevent you from pushing anything anywhere. It only **assists** you in **not committing unwanted files**. Even in that context, it does not prevent you, as you can always add any file via `git add -f`, and such files will be sent to any remotes during push just like normal file (which they, in fact, are).

Note that those 2 commands you've shown use different repos:

...git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME_PRODUCTION.git
...git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git

maybe this was what fooled you into thinking git-ignore made the difference?

Comment: A couple points of clarification:  `HEAD` means "what's checked out right now". *If* that's a branch, then it refers to the latest commit on that branch (as does the branch name itself); but if not (i.e. in detached `HEAD` state) there's no branch to talk about; it's just the current commit.  Also, the default branch mapping is governed by several config options, so surprises are quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax for `git push` is:

```
git push <remote> <refspec>
```

The last argument, the one you're interested in, generally has the form `<local-branch>:<remote-branch>`, which means "push the my branch named  to the remote, in a branch named ". There are several shortcuts:

- `git push <remote> <branch>` (without the `:`, for example `git push origin master`) is a shortcut for `git push <remote> <branch>:<branch>`, i.e. push a local branch to a remote branch with the same name.
- `git push <remote> HEAD` means push the current branch to a branch with the same name on the remote. This is the first command you write in your question.

The second command you mention is the general case: `HEAD:master` means "push the current branch to the master branch on the remote repository".

If you see a difference, you're on a local branch other than master, say `my-branch`. `HEAD` alone pushes to `my-branch` on the remote. `HEAD:master` pushes to `master` regardless of your current branch.